# Hinder overlapping axis labels in plot3D

Tags: r, plot, 3d, axis-labels

I am supposed to do 3d barplot and I found [this](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/impressive-package-for-3d-and-4d-graph-r-software-and-data-visualization) peace of code where I added axis labels. I get the following plot:

[image: Plot]

The problem is that the axis tick mark labels and axis labels overlap. How can we prevent that?

The code is:

```
library(plot3D)
data(VADeaths)
hist3D (x = 1:5, y = 1:4, z = VADeaths,
        bty = "g", phi = 20,  theta = -60,
        xlab = "My_x_lab", ylab = "My_y_lab", zlab = "", main = "VADeaths",
        col = "#0072B2", border = "black", shade = 0.8,
        ticktype = "detailed", space = 0.15, d = 2, cex.axis = 1e-9)
# Use text3D to label x axis
 text3D(x = 1:5, y = rep(0.5, 5), z = rep(3, 5),
       labels = rownames(VADeaths),
       add = TRUE, adj = 0)
# Use text3D to label y axis
 text3D(x = rep(1, 4),   y = 1:4, z = rep(0, 4),
       labels  = colnames(VADeaths),
       add = TRUE, adj = 1)
```

Comment: Try empty labs `xlab='', ylab='', ...` and then use `mtext3d` with `at=NULL` and `line=2` or greater to build the custom labels in a different line.